# How to smooth horizontal collapse transition with React-Bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

**Edit**: CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dawn-q9zow

I'm creating a React app that I want to have a collapsible sidebar. I'm using the [transition collapse utility from React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/utilities/transitions/#collapse). Since this is for a sidebar, I'm using `dimension="width"`. I've tried adding a transition to a few elements including the `.width` class as it says in the React-Bootstrap documentation, but the animation is still really choppy/not smooth. Am I missing a class, or is there something additional I need to do with the CSS?

JSX:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Collapse from 'react-bootstrap/Collapse';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";
import '../../custom_styles/sidebar.css';

function Visualizer() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="container-fluid h-100 p-0">
                <div className="row h-100 no-gutters">
                <Collapse id="sidebar" dimension="width" in={open}>
                    <div className="col-4 bg-dark text-white" id="example-collapse-text">
                        <h2>Palette</h2>
                    </div>
                </Collapse>
                    <div className="col-8">
                        <Button
                        className="float-left ml-n1"
                        variant="dark"
                        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                        aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
                        aria-expanded={open}
                        >
                        <div id="collapse-btn-text">Toggle Sidebar</div>
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Visualizer;
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    transition: width 2s;
}

.width {
    transition: width 2s;
}

.show {
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

Comment: Notice that it says in the docs: "If you're noticing choppy animations, and the component that's being collapsed has non-zero margin or padding, try wrapping the contents of your <Collapse> inside a node with no margin or padding, like the <div> in the example below. This will allow the height to be computed properly, so the animation can proceed smoothly." Does this help?

Comment: @i.brod I just did that and it made it so that the first quarter of the expand was smooth, then it jumped to remaining 75%. Collapsing still jumped without any transition animation.

Comment: But the content of collapse is wrapped with div.col-4 bg-dark text-white . Try removing .col-4 class

Comment: @i.brod I removed the `.col-4 class` and still getting the same behavior. So the main code block now looks like `<Collapse id="sidebar" dimension="width" in={open}><div id="sideBarCollapseContent"><div className="bg-dark text-white" id="example-collapse-text"><h2>Palette</h2></div></div></Collapse>` sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Can you upload your working code to some playground?

Comment: @i.brod added a CodeSandbox link to the top of the main post

Comment: It's empty dude :D

Comment: @i.brod shoot that's my bad! First time using CodeSandbox. I updated the link, so hopefully it's working now.

Comment: Tried playing with it...sorry no clue. But i think this is generally a CSS question(css transitions particularly), not particularly unique to react-bootstrap collapse. If i were you, i would re-post the question, presenting it as a CSS problem, to attract CSS experts :D

Comment: Alright, thanks for looking anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this css

```
#sidebar {
    transition: width 2s ease;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
#sidebar.yourActiveClass {
    width: auto;
}
```

But first when you click on

```
<div id="collapse-btn-text">Toggle Sidebar</div>
```

button you shoule add "yourActiveClass" in

```
<Collapse id="sidebar" dimension="width" className={true ? "collapse width yourActiveClass" : "collapse width"} in={open}>
```

true  means your Click function if true
using this you can more smooth your section.

Comment: I made those modifications and it made the animation even more choppy.

Comment: I removed `display: block` and that made it so that the button and the sidebar are staying together when expanding/collapsing (before the button would pop out before the sidebar). The `transition: width 2s ease` still isn't doing anything though :(